# Nginx set subdomain to work with php

Tags: php, nginx

What I want to achive is this:

```
Create a subdomain my.domain.com
Execute an index.php on it
```

I created a file called my.conf and put it in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/my.conf`

Inside of it I put the nex code:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/my;

    index index.php index.html;

    server_name my.domain.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I created an A record `Type: A`, `Name: my`, `Value: my IP`

I put a file inside `/var/www/my/` called `index.php` and wrote a small echo;

I did a `nginx -t` and everything was fine.
Then `sudo service nginx restart` and `sudo systemctl reload nginx`.

Everytime when I visit my.domain.com I get the content from domain.com. It looks like my.conf doesn't do what it should do because I don't see the index.php content on my subdomain.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Edit: I also use Cloudflare.

Thanks

Comment: Have you check that your `/etc/nginx/my.conf` is really loaded?

Comment: It looks like it is included in `nginx.conf`: `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`, `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`. Also if I write some gibberish and run `nginx -t` it shows an error. So I guess it is loaded.

Comment: Sorry ... It was in conf.d, I corrected the question now.

Comment: I think problem is here  `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`  change it to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`  here is my working nginx conf https://gist.github.com/kamrankr/12a05456df785e9604b1 give them a try.

Comment: No luck. Still same result.